# Writing the payload back to HTTPRequest object in Java Filter after changing some value in the payload

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot

In our application, I have to write a Filter which will read the HttpServletRequest containing xml as body. I have read the xml and now i want to remove a specific tag from the xml as it is base64 encoded content and it is taking up alot of memory while processing. I have removed the tag from xml after reading the request. Now i want this new xml string to again get added to the HttpServletRequest so that it can be processed further.
I am not able to figure out how do i add back the new string to the HttpServletRequest as body and not as parameters.  I am not looking for Interceptor solution as i am facing another issue with Interceptor in conversion.

Below is my Filter :

```
@Component
public class UploadDocumentFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        InputStream stream = request.getInputStream();
        for (int length; (length = stream.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        } // StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() > JDK 7 String test=
        String test=result.toString("UTF-8");
        //TODO add back this string back to HttpServletRequest
         
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Isakots: i did not find code to write using the ServletRequestWrapper back to the httpRequest.